# How to handle "emphasis added" etc. in Biblatex In-Line citation

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Using inline-citation (i.e. Harvard): When citing a source, you add an emphasis ("emphasis added") or modify a translation ("translation modified") etc.
This is usually pointed out directly in the reference.

Something along those lines:

> And this "was *very* important" (Author, year, p. 133, emphasis added) to me.

This is the current setup:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[%
            style=authoryear-ibid,
            backend=biber,
            autocite=inline,
            backref=true,
            backrefstyle=none,
            doi=false,
            isbn=false,
            ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

If I use

```
\autocite[133]{citekey}
```

I get: **(Author, Date, p. 144)**, which is fine.

But if I use something like

```
\autocite[133, emphasis added]{citekey}
```

I get: **(Author, Date, 144, emphasis added)**. Note that it is lacking the "p.", it does no longer seem to read the 144 as a page number.

Is there any way to do this other than adding the p. by hand in all these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an up-to-date `biblatex` (I use v3.16 to test the example, some things may also work in older versions), you have the following options

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-ibid, ibidpage]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\let\passifpages\@firstofone
\NumCheckSetup{\let\passifpages\@gobble}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}

ipsum \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}

\citereset
Lorem \autocite[\pno~381, emphasis added]{sigfridsson}

ipsum \autocite[\pno~381, emphasis added]{sigfridsson}

\citereset
Lorem \autocite[\pnfmt{382}, emphasis added]{sigfridsson}

ipsum \autocite[\pnfmt{382}, emphasis added]{sigfridsson}

\citereset
Lorem \autocite[383\passifpages{, emphasis added}]{sigfridsson}

ipsum \autocite[383\passifpages{, emphasis added}]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, p. 380)//ipsum (ibid.)////Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, p. 381, emphasis added)//ipsum (ibid., p. 381, emphasis added)////Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, p. 382, emphasis added)//ipsum (ibid., p. 382, emphasis added)////Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, p. 383, emphasis added)//ipsum (ibid.)]

- `\pno` just prints the page prefix (you'd use `\ppno` for "pages").
- `\pnfmt` applies the usual field format only to its argument, which in this case creates the "p." prefix.
- `\passifpages` hides its argument from the page and number tests, which also means that we get to see the "p." prefix here. Essentially the argument of `\passifpages` becomes invisible to `biblatex`'s formatting and tracking features.

Often the difference between `\pnfmt` and `\passifpages` does not matter, but there is a difference with the `ibidpage` with your style, because for that option it matters whether or not the argument passes the `\ifpages` test (which `\pnfmt` does not necessarily allow for, but `\passifpages` does).

Comment: Interesting reading: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/870, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/918, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1076.

Comment: Thank you!
Especially the \pnfmt and the \passifpages seem perfect - if I understand correctly (sorry, newbie here) the \pno would print the prefix always. So if I later want to change to (Author, Year: 56) it would end up giving me (Author, Year: p. 56) (at least when I just tried it).

Is there a reason to prefer \pnfmt over \passifpages or the other way round? Anything to consider?

Comment: @Scharlatan Yes, `\pno` literally just prints "p." (or whatever the page prefix comes out as in your chosen localisation). If you later change your field format to generally omit the "p.", postnotes with `\pno` will look out of place, since they will retain the "p.". I'll edit the answer in a sec with an example showing how the `\pnfmt` and `\passifpages` approaches differ. (I personally think the `\pnfmt` approach looks nicer in the code, but `\passifpages` sometimes gets closer to what people actually want.)

Comment: @moewe, I reckon it would be nice to have a robust `\ifbegnumeral` macro (and variants for ranges and pages) that could be switched in to `\makepageprefix` if desired to, for example, test if a `postnote` begins with a page or page range.

Comment: @DavidPurton Yeah. The whole business is a bit tricky as it involves several different tests (`\ifnumeral`, `\ifnumerals`, `\ifpages`) at several different levels ("p." vs "pp." as well as just plain `\ifpages` for `ibidpage` and friends). I guess best would be a clean interface that separates an optional textual note from the pages note (e.g. as discussed in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/918#issuecomment-635789954), but I don't think we can pull that off in a backwards compatible way. ...

Comment: ... In the absence of such a clear interface something like `\ifbegnumeral` might be helpful, though it alone wouldn't be enough, we'd still need code that can extract only the numeric part and work with that. I have no idea how that could be pulled off with the current implementation of things, but maybe LaTeX3 and its regexes could help? If you have any suggestions, please don't hesitate to head over to https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues

Comment: @moewe, I know it's tricky because I tried to do it :/. But regex might be a way forward, but it would still be complex since you can modify what `biblatex` considers page range characters.

Comment: And range commands. Macros make everything nasty.

Comment: I just stumbled over a further problem. I've been using the `\pnfmt{}` solution @moewe suggested, which works fine in Latex. But I've been using pandoc to convert to docx (for collaboration purposes...) and it does no longer recognize pagenumbers once they are marked as `pnfmt{}`. Here's probably not the place to ask about a pandoc fix, but just to flag that up before somebody else goes through an entire document ;-)