# Pandoc citeproc not recognizting pnfmt{}

Tags: biblatex, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

Situation:

- I'm converting from .tex to .docx (for collaboration purposes...) using pandoc.
- Because I use a lot of citations with "emphasis added" (using authordate) I am using `pnfmt{}`to apply the field format only to the page numbers. This is explained on texse [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595681/how-to-handle-emphasis-added-etc-in-biblatex-in-line-citation).

So, many of my citations look like this:

```
First citation \autocite[382]{sigfridsson1999}
Second citation \autocite[\pnfmt{382}]{sigfridsson1999}
Third citation \autocite[\pnfmt{382}, emphasis added]{sigfridsson1999}
```

Using pandoc,

```
pandoc --bibliography=references.bib --citeproc -o out.docx main.tex
```

I get the proper output on the first citation, but not on the second and third:

> First citation (Sigfridsson, 1999, p. 382)

> Second citation (Sigfridsson, 1999)

> Third citation (Sigfridsson, 1999, emphasis added)

Any way to get pandoc to recognize the `\pnfmt{}` and print the page number in the 2nd and 3rd citation?

Comment: If this works correctly when you compile with LaTeX, then it stands to reason that the "problem" is on the pandoc/citeproc side. I suspect they simply don't know `\pnfmt`, which is fairly new. It is probably worth reporting this to the maintainers so they can consider adding supporting `\pnfmt` (if they think that would be useful, the semantics of `\pnfmt` might be a bit weird, because it is essentially a trick to work around `biblatex`'s auto-formatting features).

Comment: Yeah, it is an issue on the Pandoc side. @ DG' s answer below seems to work fine as a workaround and for the occasional compile to docx it should be enough. :) Havent tested @Marijn's longer answer yet. Just thought to give everybody in the other thread a heads up as well, in case they are including some pandoc in their workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandoc can parse your own definitions, adding the dummy `\renewcommand\pnfmt[1]{#1}` somewhere in your document (you could add a file that contains the line with the option `--include-in-header=FILE`) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways, but an easy workaround could be to (re)define `\pnfmt` in the document itself to let Pandoc/citeproc use that definition. Of course this means that you do not get the usual processing of `\pnfmt` that handles all different cases, but for sharing the document with a collaborator that may not be such a big problem as long as you produce the end result with LaTeX (in which case you need to remove the redefinition again).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-ibid, ibidpage]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\def\pnfmt#1{, pg. #1}
First citation \autocite[382]{sigfridsson}
Second citation \autocite[\pnfmt{382}]{sigfridsson}
Third citation \autocite[\pnfmt{382}, emphasis added]{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]